# Evaluation of a definite integral involving logarithms and square roots

Tags: integration

**I really don't understand this, please someone help me!**

[image]

Comment: Looks a simple application of change of variables in integration. What do you not get here?

Comment: I do not understand the step when they say "thus"

Comment: This derivation is really sweet (I like it) - they add the first representation of $I$ (after "Let ...") to the second (after "we have $I=\cdots=\cdots$") to get $2I$. The variables ($x$ or $y$) are just arbitrary labels, one could also write $z$ for both.

Comment: oh I see! wow, thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can even look it at like this since : $$\int_a^bf(x) dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$,

Let $$ I =\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln (9-x)}}{\sqrt{\ln (9-x)}+\sqrt{\ln (x+3)}}$$
 Then $$I=\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\ln (3+x)}}{\sqrt{\ln (3+x)}+\sqrt{\ln (9-x)}}$$

Adding these two we have $$2I=\int_2^41dx=2$$. Hence $I =1$

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

The two different forms of $I$ are simply being added. Notice that we can write $\int_2^4{\frac{\sqrt{\ln(y+3)}}{\sqrt{\ln(y+3)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-y)}}}dy$ as $\int_2^4{\frac{\sqrt{\ln(x+3)}}{\sqrt{\ln(x+3)}+\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}}}dx$

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested information.